# Kivy doesn't open a window (PyCharm)

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

So for a few days now I've been trying to install all the modules I need for a project I'm working on, but I can't seem to be able to install kivy. I went to the settings and the interpreter installed Kivy and copied the code to open  a window from the internet, but it doesn't work. It only shows this error:

```
    /usr/bin/python3.5 "/home/justas/Documents/Development/Projects/Project     Manager/main.py"
    [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/justas/.kivy    /logs/kivy_19-01-28_2.txt
    [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.1
    [INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.5.3 (default, Sep 27 2018, 17:25:39) 
    [GCC 6.3.0 20170516]
    [INFO   ] [Factory     ] 179 symbols loaded
    [INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
    [INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
    [INFO   ] [OSC         ] using <multiprocessing> for socket
    [INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2(['window_egl_rpi'] ignored)
    [CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider at all!
    egl_rpi - ImportError: cannot import name 'bcm'
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 59,     in core_select_lib
       fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
     File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_egl_rpi.py", line 12, in <module>
    from kivy.lib.vidcore_lite import bcm, egl

    sdl2 - TypeError: expected bytes, str found
       File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 67, in core_select_lib
         cls = cls()
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 138, in __init__
    super(WindowSDL, self).__init__()
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/__init__.py", line 722, in __init__
         self.create_window()
       File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 237, in create_window
        self.fullscreen, resizable, state)
      File "kivy/core/window/_window_sdl2.pyx", line 94, in kivy.core.window._window_sdl2._WindowSDL2Storage.setup_window (kivy/core/window/_window_sdl2.c:1936)

x11 - ImportError: No module named 'kivy.core.window.window_x11'
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
 Exception ignored in: 'kivy.properties.dpi2px'
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/utils.py", line 513, in __get__
     retval = self.func(inst)
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/metrics.py", line 175, in dpi
     EventLoop.ensure_window()
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/base.py", line 126, in ensure_window
     sys.exit(1)
 SystemExit: 1
[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: This indicates that your kivy is not installed properly, it's missing some compiled components. How did you install it?

Comment: I firs tried to install it in PyCharm, it didn't work. Then I tried to install it in the console after a bit of trying it worked, then I went back to PyCharm and installed it.